# Help in Pascal writing a word counter

Tags: pascal

I have to write a program in Pascal which has to detect how many words on a text (input by the user) start with a certain letter. I can't use arrays, can you give me any hints as to where to start?

Comment: Thks all, the problem was solve =D.

Answer (score 3):

If you know which letter, you merely need to keep a counter, no need for arrays.

If you don't know which letter, keep 26 counters. Stupid, but works as per your spec.

Comment: If you don't know which letter and can't use arrays, then the homework setter needs to be shot.  You'd have to use a case statement (26-ways, or maybe 52-ways, unless you live in Europe and need to deal with accented letters) and increment ... oh heck; it doesn't bear thinking about.  It is hard enough to be using Pascal without having to use it with one hand tied behind your back.

Comment: Unless the homework setter is trying to weed out the meek and the weak. Some programming tasks, you will eventually need to have the grit to do the equivalent of 26 counters :(

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is define the set of characters that constitute letters, or conversely which ones constitute non-letters.

Write a function that takes a character and returns a boolean based on whether that character is a letter. Then loop through the string and call it for each character. When you detect a letter right after a non-letter or at the start of the string, increment your counter if it is the target letter.

Answer (score 0):

count instances of SPACE LETTER plus first word if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

(S) is your input string;

1. Create a for loop that goes from 1 to the length of (S) - 1.
2. Inside loop, check is (S)[i] = ' ' and (S)[i+1] = 't' where i is the loop counter and 't' is the letter starting the word you want to count
3. If criteria in step two matches then increment a counter.

Note the minus one on the loop size.

Also, remember that the very first letter of the string may be the one you want to match and that will not get picked up by the loop defined above.

If you need to make your code smarter in that it can locate a specific letter rather than a hardcoded 't' then you can pass the requested character as a parameter to the function/procedure that your loop is in.

Answer (score -2):

Off the top of my head - not tested

```
function WordCount(const S: string; const C: Char): Integer;
const
  ValidChars: Set of Char [A..Z, a..z]; // Alter for appropriate language
var
  i : Integer;
  t : string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Length(S) <> 0 then
  begin
    t := Trim(S); // lose and leading and trailing spaces
    t := t + ' '; // make sure a space is the last char
    repeat
      if (t[1] in ValidChars) and (t[1] = C then
        inc(Result);
      i := Pos(' ', t);
      t := Copy(t(i+1, Length(t));
    until Length(t) = 0;
  end;
end;
```

Why would you need an array or a case statement?

Comment: I thought it was right to show an example because the questioner has loaded the question towards "Array-thinking" by stating that he can't use them. When it was never an array-based problem.